# How Ubuntu decides where to position newly opened windows? Seems random to me?

Tags: windows, compiz

They open all over the place for me. Rarely at the last opened position. Seems random. Is there a way to make them open where and the size they have been closed last time? Easy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CompizConfig Settings Manager (should be installed by default) allows for the following options (and has "smart" as the default):

> **Cascade**
>
> Starts near but not at the top-left corner. Following windows go in a column downwards, the left edges aligned, until the vertical space is consumed. The next columns start at the same vertical position as the first window, unless this window is taller than the first window in the previous column, in which case it starts at the same vertical position as a lower window in the previous column.
>
> **Centered**
>
> Every single window starts perfectly centered in the screen, all on top of each other.
>
> **Smart**
>
> Each window goes as far towards the top-left corner as it can, without covering any other windows. If there is no empty space big enough to hold it, it goes wherever it covers the most empty space (the desktop) and the least other windows possible.
>
> **Maximized**
>
> **Random**
>
> **Pointer**

Comment: perfect answer! this explains that behavior.

Comment: Most seem logical but I have no idea what "pointer" does :D

Comment: how about place windows with top-left edge at cursor?

Comment: Very informative, thank you! And is there a way to make it just open it at the position and size it was last closed?